# POSTing json using java

Tags: java, json

I am trying to post this JSON to create a mock service:

```
{
  "port": "9091",
  "protocol": "http",
  "stubs": [
    {
      "responses": [
        {
          "is": {
            "headers": {
               "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": "{
                      \"type\": \"simpleRefno\"

              }"
          }
        }
      ],
      "predicates": [
        {
          "and": [
            {
              "equals": {
                "method": "GET"
              }
            },
            {
              "contains": {
                "path": "fortune_cookie"
              }
            },
            {
              "deepEquals": {
                "query": {
                  "type": "latest"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and to post above given json file I am using below given code -

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

         String t =getStringFromInputStream( );
        // System.out.println(t);
         sendPost( t);

    }

    private static String getStringFromInputStream( ) throws IOException {

        // The name of the file to open.

        Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("//TestFactory//mbjson//", "newres1.json");

        String contents  = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return contents;
    }




    private static void sendPost(String urlParameter) throws Exception {

        String url = "http://127.0.0.1:2525/imposters";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = urlParameter;
        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

}
```

This is to create a mock web service for my application, this was working fine for HTML and XML type, since I moved to json type, I am not able to POST given json to my mock server.

below is the error I am facing -

```
Sending 'POST' request to URL : http://127.0.0.1:2525/imposters
Exception in thread "main" Post parameters : {
  "port": "9091",
  "protocol": "http",
  "stubs": [
    {
      "responses": [
        {
          "is": {
            "headers": {
               "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": "{
                      \"type\": \"simpleRefno\"

              }"
          }
        }
      ],
      "predicates": [
        {
          "and": [
            {
              "equals": {
                "method": "GET"
              }
            },
            {
              "contains": {
                "path": "fortune_cookie"
              }
            },
            {
              "deepEquals": {
                "query": {
                  "type": "latest"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Response Code : 400
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://127.0.0.1:2525/imposters
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1676)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1672)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1245)
    at com.capitalone.mountebank.Test.sendPost(Test.java:65)
    at com.capitalone.mountebank.Test.main(Test.java:24)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://127.0.0.1:2525/imposters
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1627)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at com.capitalone.mountebank.Test.sendPost(Test.java:59)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: my backend is mounte bank mock server, it creates imposter with POSTed json file.

Answer (score 0):

The 400 response code from the server indicates a 'Bad Request'.

1) Insert

```
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
```

below where you set the other request property and the HTTP POST request method.

2) Remove the quotation marks outside of the brackets in the "body" field

So in the error message you provided it should be

```
"body": {
   "type": "depositAccountTransaction"
}
```

and in the original JSON file you provided it should be

```
"body": {
   "type": "simpleRefno"
}
```

That will also get rid of the need to use an escape sequence on the nested quotation marks.

Comment: So the content type is certainly necessary so keep that even if it still did not work.

Comment: I edited my answer above. I believe that should fix it.

Comment: Also you can use a JSON validator such as [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) to ensure that you have valid JSON.

Comment: I had to change the body, as it was project specific , however I forgot to change it in the error, I have downloaded JSON Lint to verify my json. thanks.

Comment: And whoever has down voted, Thanks it really helped me in finding the answer, I hope you'd keep up the good work.